How can I construct a projective representation when the group is not simply connected?
S. Weinberg, in his book "The quantum theory of fields", states this theorem (page 83): The phase of any projective representation $U(T)$ of a given group can be chosen so that $\phi =0$ if two conditions are met:

(a) The generators of the group in this representation can be redefined, so as to eliminate all central charges from the Lie algebra.

(b) The group is simply connected.


This theorem was proved in Appendix B of the book. He says in page 84 that there are just two ways that intrinsically projective representations may arise: either algebraically, because the group is represented projectively even near the identity, or topologically, because the group is not simply connected. I don't understand how to construct intrinsically projective representations by these two ways.
I really appreciate if someone could tell me how can I construct an intrinsically projective representation at least when the group is not simply connected.
My try: I found this thesis https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-61878-4 in which the author says that

"any one-dimensional unitary representation of the fundamental group of $G$, multiplying an exact unitary representation of $G$, produces
a projective unitary representation of $G$."

I just could prove that if $T:G\to GL(H)$ is a projective unitary representation of $G$ in a Hilbert space $H$, then $T_1:\pi_1 (G,f)\to \mathbb{C}^*$ defined by $[\gamma ]\to e^{i\phi (\gamma)}$ is a one-dimensional unitary representation of the
fundamental group of $G$ (indeed, since $T$ is a projective representation, $\phi (\gamma)\in \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $T(\gamma(1))=e^{i\phi (\gamma)}T(\gamma (0))$).
